# Problems of installing scikit-learn in Python

Tags: python, pip, scikit-learn

I was trying to install python package scikit-­learn. I keep get an error.

I tried

```
 pip install scikit­-learn
```

The error looks like following. What is the problem of my installation?

```
compile options: '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c'

c++: sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: Command "c++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-GYuqQN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/johnkuk/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I also tried several different ways to install the package. From easy_install, I also got following error message.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Setup script exited with error: Command "c++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c /private/tmp/easy_install-oD3dwa/scikit-learn-0.14.1/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/private/tmp/easy_install-oD3dwa/scikit-learn-0.14.1/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o" failed with exit status 1
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
  from numpy.distutils import log
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with your LLVM installation. Are you sure you have the latest version of XCode CLI tools?

Comment: scikit-learn takes its compiler args from NumPy and it looks like your NumPy was compiled with GCC, so you need to compile with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same trouble today, after trying many things the one that worked me was setting some environment variables before installing with pip resolved the issue for me:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

And then install with sudo:

```
sudo -E pip install -U scikit-learn
```

it's seems to be a problem with xcode update (5.1.1 for me), it does not accept '-mno-fused-madd' as an argument, before it threw it a warning, know is an error, the first two commands ignore the unused arguments witch are the same that throw the error.

Hope it helps, any comments/corrections are welcome.

Comment: Worked for me as well, running Mavericks